# Is it possible to install Canon EOS T3 Camera Drivers on Windows 7 Embedded

Tags: windows-embedded-7

I have a computer running Windows 7 Embedded. It's an embedded system that will be used in a industrial setting. It needs to be connected to a Canon EOS camera and download pictures from the camera. Other versions of windows come with the Canon drivers so Canon does not provide them as a download on their website.

In the past, I had a similar issue with the "N" version of Microsoft Windows Starter and had to download the "Microsoft Media Feature Pack" which then installed the drivers. I attempted to install that on this device, but understandably it complains that its not applicable for this version of windows.

So, is there there a feature pack or some other sort of download available that will install the camera drivers? Alternatively, is there some place to get the drivers and manually install them.

Thanks in Advance,
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking your system, installing Windows 7 Pro on it, configure and connect the camera and then run [TAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/librAry/ff794097%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx) to gather the required drivers.  I've found that some USB devices that emulate serial devices for commands sometimes require additional WES7 driver packages (MDMCPQ2 in particular for the Arduino).  Installing the Windows Media Player package should be sufficient to give you the same components as the "Microsoft Media Feature Pack".